# Two-Way Sync or Dynamic Leak Between 2 cell ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sync, code

Below is code on a Dynamic Link or 2-Way Sync between two separate sheets and fields. However, I would like to change this to do a range of fields such as A4:A12 and B7:B15. Please help. **Updated for a range using a For loop but cannot edit multiple cells without error**

Sheet1 = a field on the dateref sheet

VBA Code for 2 sheets.

**In Sheet 1:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then

   If Target = Range("A4") Then

      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").Value = Target.Value

   End If

End If

End Sub
```

**In Sheet 2**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then

    If Target = Range("B7") Then

        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value <> Target.Value Then

      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = Target.Value

    End If

  End If

End If

End Sub
```

New Code but errors when two fields are edited at once.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Rng = Array("B11", "B12")

Rng2 = Array("C13", "C14")

Sched = Sheets("Dateref").Range("A7")

For i = 0 To UBound(Rng) - LBound(Rng)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Rng(i))) Is Nothing Then

  If Target = Range(Rng(i)) Then

    If Sheets(Sched).Range(Rng2(i)).Value <> Target.Value Then

      Sheets(Sched).Range(Rng2(i)).Value = Target.Value

    End If

  End If

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Nick Peretti ,, if I'm not wrong long back I've has posted both of the codes to tallish two way link between sheets,, did you try replacing single cell with the RANGE?

Comment: I attempted to do example:    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4：A12")) Is Nothing Then 

     but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4：A12")) Is Nothing Then
```

&

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B7:B15").Value = Target.Value
```

instead of

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
```

&

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").Value = Target.Value
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this. It wouldn't function. However, I did sort of come up with a solution See my edit to question